# Discord bot can not read files with commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I put this into my code:
`const pmie = require("./commands/pmie.js");`

and I made directory commands and put file "pmie.js" in there

This is code in file pmie.js:

```
const Disocrd = require("discord.js");
const client = new Disocrd.Client();
const prefix = ""


client.on("message", (message)=>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "pmie")){
        let author = message.member;
        let role = message.guild.roles.find('name', "Founder");
        if(author.roles.has(role.id)){
            message.reply("You have Permission.");
            return
        }else{
            message.reply("You don't have permission");
        }

    }
    
})
```

But bot does not do anything when I use "pmie" command, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To fix that you would need something like this.

pmie.js:

```js
module.exports = function (client, message, Discord, prefix) {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "pmie")){
        let author = message.member;
        let role = message.guild.roles.find('name', "Founder");
        if(author.roles.has(role.id)){
            message.reply("You have Permission.");
            return
        }else{
            message.reply("You don't have permission");
        }

    }
```

Your main javascript file:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
   const pmie = require("./commands/pmie.js")
   pmie(client, message, Discord, prefix)
})
```

Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Keep saying "client missing intents"

Comment: I made brand new code only with your code and now it says:
}


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

On the last lane

Comment: Could I have the full error?

Comment: I am confused, now it says this:

C:\Users\thoma\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');


[Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}